# Running Express.js in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I tried install express (using -g for global) in Windows 7 using

```
 npm install -g express
```

I get the following and no errors:

```
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
 ...
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
 npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
 npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/0.8.0
 express@4.1.1 C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express
 ├── methods@0.1.0
 ├── parseurl@1.0.1
 ..    
 ├── type-is@1.1.0 (mime@1.2.11)
 └── accepts@1.0.1 (negotiator@0.4.3, mime@1.2.11)
```

When I type express, I get:

```
 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Why would you type `express`, it's a node module that you require ?

Comment: I had to use npm install -g express-generator. That solved the issue. I was trying to use express to create an app. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem on Windows 8.1
use this command

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

or

```
npm install -g express-generator@'version'
```

like

```
npm install -g express-generator@3
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is not meant to be run on command prompt.
If you're trying to generate the base express project then you can use express-generator, you can install it using:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

After success installtion, then to generate an express project:

1. Go the directory on your hard drive.
2. run the following command: `express myProject`
3. It will generate the base project for you.
4. using your command prompt go to the created folder by the previous command.
5. you can run now your project using one of the following commands:

   ```
   npm start OR node myProject
   ```